# Link to both LLDB and clang in the same executable

Tags: c++, llvm, lldb, llvm-clang, llvm-c++-api

I'm trying to create an exectuable that uses both LLDB and clang (The C++ API, not the libclang C API) but I'm coming across an error: clang initializes it's commandline parameters statically and because LLDB has it's own copy of clang linked in, then it is initialized twice, and I get this error:

`: CommandLine Error: Option 'enable-value-profiling' registered more than once!
LLVM ERROR: inconsistency in registered CommandLine options`

### Steps to reproduce

Compile the file

```
// main.cpp
#include <memory>

#include <clang/CodeGen/CodeGenAction.h>

int main() {
    auto compilerAction = std::make_unique<clang::EmitLLVMOnlyAction>(nullptr);
}
```

With the commandline

```
g++  main.cpp  -std=c++14 \
    -llldb \
    -lclangRewrite -lclangFrontendTool -lclangCodeGen \
    -lclangFrontend -lclangParse -lclangSerialization \
    -lclangSerialization -lclangSema -lclangEdit -lclangAnalysis \
    -lclangAST -lclangLex -lclangDriver -lclangBasic -lLLVM
```

Then run it:

```
./a.out
```

## My Environment

I'm running a fully updated Arch Linux, LLVM version 4.0, which is LLVM 4 built like this:

```
  cmake \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr \
    -DLLVM_BUILD_LLVM_DYLIB=ON \
    -DLLVM_LINK_LLVM_DYLIB=ON \
    -DLLVM_INSTALL_UTILS=ON \
    -DLLVM_ENABLE_RTTI=ON \
    -DLLVM_ENABLE_FFI=ON \
    -DLLVM_BUILD_TESTS=ON \
    -DLLVM_BUILD_DOCS=ON \
    -DLLVM_ENABLE_SPHINX=ON \
    -DLLVM_ENABLE_DOXYGEN=OFF \
    -DLLDB_DISABLE_LIBEDIT=1 \
    -DSPHINX_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS=OFF \
    -DFFI_INCLUDE_DIR=$(pkg-config --variable=includedir libffi) \
    -DLLVM_BINUTILS_INCDIR=/usr/include \
    .. && make
```

## Things that make the problem not happen:

1. Remove `-llldb` from the commandline
2. Remove that function call in main

What makes sense to me as a good solution is only linking to lldb, and not clang, and rely on lldb's copy of clang to call clang. This seems to not work, I get linker errors:

```
$ clang++  main.cpp -I .. -std=c++14 -llldb -lLLVM           
/tmp/main-14b759.o: In function `std::_MakeUniq<clang::EmitLLVMOnlyAction>::__single_object std::make_unique<clang::EmitLLVMOnlyAction, decltype(nullptr)>(decltype(nullptr)&&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZSt11make_uniqueIN5clang18EmitLLVMOnlyActionEJDnEENSt9_MakeUniqIT_E15__single_objectEDpOT0_[_ZSt11make_uniqueIN5clang18EmitLLVMOnlyActionEJDnEENSt9_MakeUniqIT_E15__single_objectEDpOT0_]+0x51): undefined reference to `clang::EmitLLVMOnlyAction::EmitLLVMOnlyAction(llvm::LLVMContext*)'
clang-4.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Are you linking to the lldb dylib?  If so this failure is expected, the lldb dylib only exports the SB API's.  That's its public interface.  You might have more luck linking with the liblldb.a and all the other .a files that go into making the lldb dylib.

Comment: I don't see a `liblldb.a`, I the SB APIs are compiled directly into `liblldb.so`, according to the link command.